# Usefulness of having a cryogenic controller at 4K for transmons/spin qubits

Tags: architecture, quantum-control

There have been plenty of papers on the design of cryogenic control chips working at ~4K for qubit control and readout. These papers talk about how running coaxial cables from room temperature control electronics to the qubits inside the dilution refrigerator is not scalable and hence a cryogenic chip will be able to scale much better. However, after reading these papers, I'm still not convinced that such cryogenic chips could absolutely be needed as the number of qubits are scaled up. This is because the cable constraint could be alleviated (partially if not entirely) by using schemes like a [cryogenic switch matrix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2202.pdf).

**Are there other, more subtle reasons for using cryogenic CMOS based controllers other than the decrease in cables running from room temperature to the dilution refrigerator?** From my understanding, the number of cables needed to control the qubits from 4K would still remain the same and with lower cooling powers at the colder stages of the dilution refrigerator, the chip might not be able to control a lot of qubits anyway!

Some of the papers I'm referring to are listed here-

1. [Horseridge II](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9365762)
2. [Cryo CMOS controller I](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8865458)
3. [Cryo CMOS controller II](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9209175)